# Replace tabs with spaces in Visual Studio project files (sln & vcproj)

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to have a strict no-tab policy at my company by adding blockers on commits which introduce tabs.

Problem is visual studio uses tabs for their .sln & .vcproj files even when your settings are set to use spaces instead of tabs in the VS editor.

Anyone know how I can change that or am I stuck making another microsoft exception?

Comment: Do you mean tabs *in* sln and vcproj?

Comment: Yes, in the sln and vcproj files.

Comment: Well, I'm not aware of any setting for this, probably because no one really cares how the sln or vcproj files look? It's a "program settings file", in contrast to a "document file", so you don't normally mock about in them. Why are you trying to restrict tabs in those files anyway?

Comment: It just requires me to add an exception for those file extensions in my anti-tab script which I was hoping to avoid - if indeed a setting existed to use spaces instead.

Comment: Oh I see, you have a script. Then I guess it makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For your information, spaces are supported in vcxproj but not in sln files. Replacing tabs by spaces in .sln will make it load incorrectly (not generate exceptions or anything).

There are no settings in visual studio itself to change that though.

There are scripts that can do it before submitting in a source control but keep in mind that .sln files must keep the tabs to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in Visual Studio 2019.

[image: VS2019]

Comment: This may work for the source code files, but doesn't seem to have any effect on the .sln solution file.

Comment: doenst work for csproj files also.